# errors with win32api.setcursorpos in python

Tags: python, winapi, keyboard, win32com, pyautogui

Okey so I'm making a "simple" bot that is supposed to play [aim booster](http://www.aimbooster.com/)

so with help from some tutorials, I made this code

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con


#color (255,219,195)
run = False

def clicker(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

while keyboard.is_pressed('w') == False:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('d') and run == False:
                run = True
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a') and run == True:
                run = False
        if run == True:
                if keyboard.is_pressed('d') and run == False:
                        run = True
                if keyboard.is_pressed('a') and run == True:
                        run = False
                pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(570,440,1330-570,975-440))
                width, height = pic.size

                for x in range (0,width,5):
                        for y in range(0,height,5):
                                r, g, b = pic.getpixel((x,y))

                                if r == 255 and g == 219 and b ==195:
                                        clicker(x+570,y+440)
                                        time.sleep(0.1)
                                        print("click")
                                        break
```

but around 6 minutes after I start running the code it gives me either a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\bot_tutorials\acurrate.py", line 35, in <module>
    clicker(x+570,y+440)
  File "C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\bot_tutorials\acurrate.py", line 13, in clicker
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

or an IOError: screen grab failed

I don't know if u need this but my computer is 1920×1080 píxels and it is a window

Thank U in advance

Comment: Does `No error message is available` occur within 6 minutes? I did not reproduce your problem, and the `IOError` seems to be caused by `ImageGrab`, but your code did not call it.

Comment: it just occurs at a random time generally after 6 minutes

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\angel\OneDrive\Escritorio\bot_tutorials\acurrate.py", line 28, in <module>
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(570,440,1330-570,975-440))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 135, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 427, in _screenshot_win32
    im = ImageGrab.grab()

Comment: File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 54, in grab
    -1,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2657, in frombytes
    im = new(mode, size)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2621, in new
    return im._new(core.fill(mode, size, color))

Comment: Please start with the minimal code sample. The code example you provided does not show `pywintypes.error` (even after a long period of time), and the way you call `SetCursorPos` is correct.  Note: Dividing your complete sample into multiple smaller samples will help solve the problem quickly.